# Accessing the Pythonanywhere Fortran Compiler via a Bash Console

Tags: bash, makefile, fortran, pythonanywhere

I am attempting to install the SBDART program (https://github.com/paulricchiazzi/SBDART) that requires the successful execution of a Fortran makefile. Upon successful installation, I plan to install and run the "RunRT" Python program (see https://github.com/paulricchiazzi/SBDART/blob/master/RunRT/RunRT.py). Currently, I'm receiving the following error when I try to execute the SBDART makefile:

[Screenshot of the Bash console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hPTj.png)

12:36 ~/PHYS722/SBDART-master $ make

/usr/local/bin/gfortran -O -C -std=f2003 -Wuninitialized -c -o params.o params.f make: /usr/local/bin/gfortran: Command not found

make: *** [params.o] Error 127

How can I access the Fortran compiler via the PythonAnywhere Bash console? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Sincerely, Ken

Comment: Do you think `/usr/local/bin/gfortran` exists?  Is gfortran installed somewhere else if it is installed?  If you have the variable `FC` refer to where it is installed, does it work?

Comment: You need to understand the reasons and implications of `/usr/local/bin/gfortran: Command not found`. I recommend reading up on [PATH variable](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html), https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225736/how-does-a-shell-execute-a-program, and ways to install a compiler on your Linux distribution. Then my guess is that you need to make sure `gfortran` is installed, and replace `/usr/local/bin/gfortran` in that Makefile with just `gfortran` (which should be found on `PATH`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes- gfortran was located in a different directory as originally indicated in the makefile. The actual directory is /usr/bin/gfortran. I updated the FC variable accordingly and the SBDART program compiled correctly. Thus, lesson learned- make sure to check the actual location of gfortran before compiling! Cheers,